# Replacing NULL with either text or 0 in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, isnull

I have a database that tracks loans and paybacks from my organizations' parts inventory. They are separate tables DiversionT and PaybackT. I also have tables CustomerT and PartsT that have the customer and parts information. I have a query (with two subqueries) that has the goal of taking in a customer and part from a form and having one subquery calculate the sum of loans on a given part and a given customer.

```
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN DiversionT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = DiversionT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = DiversionT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

Another subquery sums the paybacks for the same customer and part.

```
SELECT CustomerT.CustomerProgram,PartsT.PartID,Sum(PaybackT.PayAmountParts) AS SumOfPayAmountParts
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN PaybackT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = PaybackT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = PaybackT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

These results are then differenced to get the Balance Owed and then presented for export via Excel:

```
FROM SinglePartSumQ, CustomerT, SinglePartPaybackSumQ INNER JOIN PartsT ON SinglePartPaybackSumQ.PartID = PartsT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID, PartsT.IndiaUID, PartsT.NSN, PartsT.PartName, SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY, SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]))
ORDER BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram;
```

For items that are both in DiversionT and PaybackT the query works fine however in the likely event that no payback has occurred I want the second subquery to return the customer, part ID and 0 for the sum. Right now the second subquery return blanks and therefore the final differencing query doesn't work.

I have tried to use the ISNULL function in my payback sum query where for the customer and part when null I want it to return the name and part ID and then when the sum is invariably null return 0 that way the differencing operation will use the 0.

I have tried the following implementation of ISNULL for the payback sum query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CustomerT.CustomerProgram,CustomerT.CustomerProgram), ISNULL(PartsT.PartID,PartsT.PartID), ISNULL(Sum(PaybackT.PayAmountParts),0) AS SumOfPayAmountParts
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN PaybackT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = PaybackT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = PaybackT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

However I get a run-time error '3326': This recordset is not updateable. When I try to debug it takes me to my VBA code for the form:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub AllPartSearch_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub OnePartOneCust_Click()
Dim getFolder As Object
Dim sLoc As String
Dim fileN As String
DoCmd.OpenQuery "SinglePartSumQ"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "SinglePartPaybackSumQ"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "OneCustOnePartQ"
Set getFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With getFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    fileN = Forms!PartsSearchF!FileName
    If .Show = True Then
        sLoc = getFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
End With
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "OneCustOnePartQ", sLoc & fileN & ".xlsx", True
End Sub

Private Sub PartSearch_Click()
End Sub
```

The debugger flags the second `DoCmD.OpenQuery` statement for the payback sum query and when I run the debugger I get *run-time error '3075':Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'ISNULL(CustomerT.CustomerProgram,CustomerT.CustomerProgram'.*

First is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Second what is wrong with my implementation of ISNULL?

UPDATE: I have changed my ISNULLs to NZ. The payback query return three columns Expr1,Expr2, SumofPayAmountParts with nothing in them when I used a part that had no entries in PaybackT. Also regardless of status in PaybackT the Query opens a parameter window looking for input but it should get everything from the form it needs like when the `NZ` or `ISNULL` wasn't there?
Here is my code that is now for the payback query:

```
SELECT Nz(CustomerT.CustomerProgram,CustomerT.CustomerProgram) AS Expr1, Nz(PartsT.PartID,PartsT.PartID) AS Expr2, Nz(Sum(PaybackT.PayAmountParts),0) AS SumOfPayAmountParts
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN PaybackT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = PaybackT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = PaybackT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

And here is the code for the differencing query;

```
SELECT NZ(CustomerT.CustomerProgram,CustomerT.CustomerProgram), NZ(PartsT.PartID,PartsT.PartID),NZ(PartsT.IndiaUID, PartsT.IndiaUID),NZ(PartsT.NSN,PartsT.NSN), NZ(PartsT.PartName,PartsT.PartName), NZ(SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY,SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY), NZ(SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts),SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts, SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY-SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts AS BalanceOwed
FROM SinglePartSumQ, CustomerT, SinglePartPaybackSumQ INNER JOIN PartsT ON SinglePartPaybackSumQ.PartID = PartsT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID, PartsT.IndiaUID, PartsT.NSN, PartsT.PartName, SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY, SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]))
ORDER BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram;
```

UPDATE 2: Based on some feeedback I have updated my code and all the column headings now show up in all three queries but the payback and differencing queries still show up blank.

Here is the Diversion sum query:

```
SELECT CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID, Sum(Nz(DiversionT.RcvdQTY,0)) AS SumOfRcvdQTY
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN DiversionT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = DiversionT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = DiversionT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

The Payback sum query

```
SELECT CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID, Sum(NZ((PaybackT.PayAmountParts),0)) AS SumOfPayAmountParts
FROM PartsT INNER JOIN (CustomerT INNER JOIN PaybackT ON CustomerT.CustomerID = PaybackT.CustomerID) ON PartsT.PartID = PaybackT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]));
```

and the differencing query

```
SELECT CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID,PartsT.IndiaUID,PartsT.NSN,PartsT.PartName,SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY, SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts, NZ(SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY,0)-NZ(SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts,0) AS BalanceOwed
FROM SinglePartSumQ, CustomerT, SinglePartPaybackSumQ INNER JOIN PartsT ON SinglePartPaybackSumQ.PartID = PartsT.PartID
GROUP BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram, PartsT.PartID, PartsT.IndiaUID, PartsT.NSN, PartsT.PartName, SinglePartSumQ.SumOfRcvdQTY, SinglePartPaybackSumQ.SumOfPayAmountParts
HAVING (((CustomerT.CustomerProgram)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![CustomerSearch]) AND ((PartsT.PartID)=[Forms]![PartsSearchF]![PartSearch]))
ORDER BY CustomerT.CustomerProgram;
```

I have a feeling that the issue is with the Access generated `inner join` statements and how it is looking for comparison. Since the Diversion table will never have a null condition because you wouldn't be looking if hadn't been loaned parts should I based what gets shown in the differencing table on the Diversion. Namely fixing this line in the differencing query (I just don't know how being an SQL novice):
`FROM SinglePartSumQ, CustomerT, SinglePartPaybackSumQ INNER JOIN PartsT ON SinglePartPaybackSumQ.PartID = PartsT.PartID`

Comment: Look at the `Nz` function instead of `ISNULL`.

Comment: I was literally about to say ISNULL is SQL Server, NZ is Access's version

Comment: literally replace isnull with nz and youll be fine

Comment: NZ didn't work.See above.

Comment: `NZ` should be used **only** on the `SUM()` part of the SQL - there is no point using it like `Nz(CustomerProgram,CustomerProgram)` as this is just saying "if the CustomerProgram is null, then use the CustomerProgram". Also, I suspect tthat you may need to change an INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Applecore I updated the code. I posted an update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Payback" query in design view, right-click on the join between the "CustomerT" and "PaybackT" tables, and select "Join properties" to bring up this dialog box:
[image]

Change the Join properties to be "Include ALL records from 'CustomerT' and only those records from 'PaybackT' where the joined fields are equal."

This should give you what you need.

Regards,

Comment: I get I run time error and during debug it says The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'CustomerProgram'....

Comment: OK. Start by ignoring the filters applied in the query from controls on a form, just "hard-code" some suitable values in to make sure that it runs without error.